# Windows Media Player (v12) seek position won't play from a chosen position

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

For example, if I drag it to a certain point, it will snap to a position nearby, rather than the exact position.

Is this a 'feature' and if so, how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this happen with every file you try to play, or only specific ones?
This sounds like an encoding issue (for example, a faulty AVI indexing table). Try opening in VLC and see if it comments about the video - it may also offer to rebuild the indexing table, if that's an issue it detects.

Comment: I did that. It seems that it's actually the WMV, rather than WMP. I'll close the question. Thanks.